# Unstack a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame counter-clockwise instead of clockwise

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a multiindex pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                      Number of Vulnerabilities
Name       Severity
           moderate   2167
Person 1   high       1421
           critical   2464
           moderate   5841
Person 2   high       3687
           critical   10267
```

My objective is to create a horizontal stacked bar chart with the bars, representing Severity, in left-to-right order of: moderate, high, critical. In order to get a stacked bar chart it seems like I need to unstack the Severity index column. When I try to do that, like so, `df.unstack('Severity')`, my DataFrame looks like this:

```
           Number of Vulnerabilities
Severity   critical  high  moderate
Name
Person 1   2464      1421  2167
Person 2   10267     3687  5841
```

So, when I go to plot it, the stacked bars are in order (L->R): critical, high, moderate.
How can I change the order of the 'Severity' index when unstacked to be: moderate, high, critical? Or, is there a way to change the order when plotting, eliminating the need to further operate on the DataFrame?
My current plot code is, `df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reorder your columns.

```
df = df.unstack('Severity') # This is your current dataframe

df = df['Number of Vulnerabilities'][['moderate', 'high', 'critical']] # reoder
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True) #plot
```

Comment: That works! However, 'Number of Vulnerabilities' column name is gone. Is there a way to keep it through the reorder?